# Django REST Framework: Two different ModelSerializers for the same model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have one model for which I've defined two different HyperlinkedModelSerializers:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...

class FooSerializer1(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('url', 'id', ...)
        lookup_field= 'pk'

# A second view of the same model for another API use-case
class FooSerializer2(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('url', 'id', ...)
        lookup_field= 'pk'
```

`FooSerializer1` is being used by a couple `GenericViews` in one Django app (i.e. its own urls.py), and `FooSerializer2` by a `ModelViewSet` in another Django app. I have the `ModelViewSet` registered in a `DefaultRouter` along with a few other viewsets:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.api_root'),
    url(r'^foo1/$', views.FooList1.as_view(), name='foo1-list'),
    ...
)

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)

...

class FooViewSet2(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FooSerializer2
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        ...

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
...
router.register(r'foo2', views.FooViewSet2)
...
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

That router's auto-generated api root displays the endpoint for the `GenericView` of `FooSerializer1` (`foo1-list`), instead of `foo2/`. If I manually GET `foo2/`, the results show `Foo` serialized according to `FooSerializer2` (which is correct), however the URL for each result again displays the `foo1` detail view.

I tried setting `get_serializer` in `FooViewSet2`, but that didn't work. How do I get the api-root and `FooSerializer2` results to display the URLs corresponding to `FooViewset2`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DRF fortunately allows the flexibility to support this scenario through setting a few parameters.

First, I set the `basename` parameter on the router entry:

```
router.register(r'foo2', views.Foo2ViewSet, 'foo2')
```

Next, I set the `view_name` in the `HyperlinkedModelSerializers` in order to not default to `foo-detail` as [mentioned in the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#how-hyperlinked-views-are-determined):

```
class FooSerializer1(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='foo1-detail',
    )
    ...

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.api_root'),
    url(r'^foo1/$', views.Foo1List.as_view(), name='foo1-list'),
    url(r'^foo1/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.FooDetail1.as_view(), name='foo1-detail'),

    ...

class FooSerializer2(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='foo2-detail',
    )
    ...
```